# Cannot change Shrine Amazon S3 prefix in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Shrine to directly upload image to Amazon S3 storage in my app. It works fine with the default settings. But when I'm trying to change the prefix of the uploaded image, the prefix didn't change. And of course when I then tried to view the image via the browser I got this error:

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>store/cccd4928ef62740b851f7c278a3907ef.png</Key>
....
</Error>
```

This is my current setting in **config/initializers/shrine.rb**:

```
require "shrine/storage/s3"
 
s3_options = {
    access_key_id: Rails.application.secrets.access_key_id,
    secret_access_key: Rails.application.secrets.secret_access_key,
    region: Rails.application.secrets.aws_region,  
    bucket: Rails.application.secrets.aws_bucket,  
}

if Rails.env.development?
    prefix = "dev"
else
    prefix = "prod"
end 

Shrine.storages = {
  cache: Shrine::Storage::S3.new(prefix: prefix, **s3_options), #default prefix is "cache"
  store: Shrine::Storage::S3.new(prefix: prefix, **s3_options),   #default prefix is "store"
}

Shrine.plugin :activerecord
Shrine.plugin :upload_endpoint
Shrine.plugin :restore_cached_data
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

Basically in the model where I reference Shrine ImageUploader class, I need to user `include ImageUploader::Attachment(:image)` instead of `include ImageUploader[:image]` because I'm using `Shrine.plugin :activerecord`